# TypeORMError: Driver not Connected - NestJs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config, nestjs-typeorm

I am setting up a NestJs application with TypeORM and postgres driver.

I have the required packages needed (`"pg": "^8.11.0"` and other typeorm packages).

data-source.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT
    ? parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10)
    : 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: process.env.DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true',
  dropSchema: false,
  // keepConnectionAlive: true,
  logging: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  entities: ['src/modules/**/entity/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/database/migrations/**/*.ts'],
  ssl: false,
});
```

this in main.ts

```
import {
  initializeTransactionalContext,
  addTransactionalDataSource,
} from 'typeorm-transactional';
import { AppDataSource } from 'data-source';

async function bootstrap() {
  initializeTransactionalContext();
  addTransactionalDataSource(AppDataSource);
.
.
.
.
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [databaseConfig, appConfig],
      envFilePath: ['.env'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
      dataSourceFactory: async (options) => {
        return new DataSource(options).initialize();
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and this is the error I get when I try to use database from API

```
TypeORMError: Driver not Connected
    at PostgresDriver.obtainMasterConnection (/users/qwer/app-backend/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts:1158:19)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.connect (/users/qwer/app-backend/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:110:18)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/users/qwer/app-backend/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:244:47)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.startTransaction (/users/qwer/app-backend/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:176:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at EntityManager.transaction (/users/qwer/app-backend/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts:153:13)
```

Note that I have `synchronize` set as `true`, so when I start the application, it does create tables in database.

What am I doing wrong or what is missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Could you solve the issue? I also sometimes encounter this error when running with Docker."